# Select record between specific range

Tags: sql, subquery

I currently have a very long list of records in SQL delimited by a start and a finish, in the middle I have repeated values ​​with the name of the machining.
How can I retrieve all the processes with the start and end date and associated name?
My actually query is

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 id_prod,Descrizione,Parm0,LEFT(parm1, LEN(parm1)-20) as Azione ,convert(DateTime,right(parm1,19)) as Orario FROM INPUT
    where
        Parm0 = 'programstate' and (charindex('DNC_PRG_STS_FINISHED', Parm1) > 0)
             or
         Parm0 = 'programevent' and (charindex('dnc_prg_evt_started', Parm1) > 0 )
          or
          (
              parm0='ProgramName' and (charindex('USB0', Parm1) > 0)
                  )
    order by Orario Desc
```

| id_prod | Parm0 | Azione | Orario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2755686 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:46:48.000 |
| 2755683 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:46:38.000 |
| 2755681 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:46:37.000 |
| 2755676 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:46:36.000 |
| 2755672 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:46:33.000 |
| 2755666 | ProgramState | DNC_PRG_STS_FINISHED | 2021-12-06 11:42:33.000 |
| 2755663 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:42:23.000 |
| 2755662 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:42:22.000 |
| 2755659 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:42:21.000 |
| 2755644 | ProgramState | DNC_PRG_EVT_STARTED | 2021-12-06 11:22:33.000 |
| 2755641 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:22:33.000 |
| 2755633 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:22:13.000 |
| 2755631 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:21:23.000 |

EDIT:
Thank you @LukStorms, but that's not what i need. the start, code and end groups are thousands. I wish I had such a list at the end

| id_prod | Start | Finish | Lavorazione |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-06 11:22:33.000 | 2021-12-06 11:42:33.000 | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H |
| 2 | 2021-12-06 11:11:43.000 | 2021-12-06 11:12:33.000 | \USB0\P99\Lavorazione 11.H |
| 3 | 2021-12-06 09:11:43.000 | 2021-12-06 11:42:33.000 | \USB0\P99\Produzione 322.H |
| 4 | 2021-12-02 11:11:43.000 | 2021-12-20 12:12:12.000 | \USB0\P11\Piastra 19.H |

I hope I was clear. There are thousands of processes like this and I need to take the beginning, the end and the content in the middle to be able to make it readable with a table

Comment: Is that sample data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server?)

Comment: this is a small extract of real data.
I use MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the position of the timestamp via `PATINDEX`.

**Example snippet**

> ```
> declare @input table (
>  id_prod int, 
>  parm0 varchar(100),
>  parm1 varchar(100)
> );
>
> insert into @input (id_prod, parm0, parm1) values
>   (2755686, 'ProgramName',  '\USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H2021-12-06 11:46:48') 
> , (2755644, 'ProgramEvent', 'DNC_PRG_EVT_STARTED 2021-12-06 11:22:33') 
> , (2755666, 'ProgramState', 'DNC_PRG_STS_FINISHED 2021-12-06 11:42:33') 
>
> SELECT *
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT id_prod, parm0
>     , LEFT(parm1, PATINDEX('%_20[0-9][0-9]-%', parm1)) AS Azione
>     , TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(parm1, PATINDEX('%20[0-9][0-9]-%', parm1), 19) AS DATETIME) AS Orario
>     FROM @input
>     WHERE parm0 IN ('programname', 'programevent', 'programstate')
>       AND parm1 LIKE '%2021-12%'
> ) q
> WHERE Orario BETWEEN '2021-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-12-06 23:59:59'
> ```

| id_prod | parm0 | Azione | Orario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2755686 | ProgramName | \USB0\P99\PIASTRA M8.H | 2021-12-06 11:46:48.000 |
| 2755644 | ProgramEvent | DNC_PRG_EVT_STARTED | 2021-12-06 11:22:33.000 |
| 2755666 | ProgramState | DNC_PRG_STS_FINISHED | 2021-12-06 11:42:33.000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=314573453e7423ac2c0f271c70b8b9b4)*